# Expanding a drive partition, without data loss

Tags: ubuntu, partition

Ive installed ubuntu server and the drive configuration is confusing me.

```
sda                         8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 445.1G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

My docker applications are reporting the drive as 100G and downloading media will quickly fill up the drive. I would like to either:

- Extend the main partition to 550G
- Relocate the /media folder to the 445G partition

I'm getting out of my depth when researching as gets pretty complex very quickly.

[How to resize a partition](https://www.msp360.com/resources/blog/linux-resize-partition/#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20way%20of%20resizing,to%20fit%20the%20new%20bounds.)
[How to resize a logical partition](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/resize-lvm-simple)

Can anyone tell me with some certainty what i do to make the additional space usable, and avoid losing all my data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your 100G "partition" is not a partition. It's an LVM2 logical volume.

That's good.You can increase its size trivially, for example:

```
lvresize -L +50G -r ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

That will increase the size by 50 GB, using 50 of the probably 345GB free space in your ubuntu-vg volume group.

Comment: Indeed. He will, however, have a hard time to extend a 447 GB HDD to hold a volume of 550 ;D ...

Comment: @steeldriver AFAIK using `r` or `--resizefs` will avoid using extra commands (such as `resize2fs`)

Comment: @steeldriver exactly, that's what the -r does.